# Creating texture and palette modification

Tags: sdl2

I need to create a texture from a surface with indexed color palette and alter the colors. However, after I set new colors, the rendered texture gets blank.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    init();

    gSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(gFont, "text", fg1);

    // text is rendered properly, without following line
    SDL_SetPaletteColors(gSurface->format->palette, &fg2, 1, 1);

    gTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, gSurface);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

    SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gTexture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);

    SDL_Delay(1000);

    quit();
}
```

I tested this code with software rendering using window surface instead of renderer and pallete changing worked.
Could someone explain me why does it happed and how to fix it?

Comment: What are `fg1` and `fg2`?

Comment: they are SDL_Color structures

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the fact that [SDL_SetPaletteColors](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetPaletteColors) wants an array of `SDL_Color`s as an argument instead of pointer to a single color. I cannot guarantee that this is the problem as you didn't post the code where you initialize the code, and you haven't told if `SDL_GetError()` returns an error message.

Otherwise, make sure to always check what `SDL_GetError()` returns on a SDL function you think might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I tried both an array and a single color and both approaches doesn't work with renderer and does work with window surface. In principle, pointer to the object is no different to a one element array.

I'll post more code and SDL_GetError() message if any.

Comment: Thinking about it that makes sense. Please add more code and the error message if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago I have encountered a similar issue with a short example SDL2 app. There were no mainloop as in your sample code. After mainloop added the image began to display.

Quick fix for your code seems to be:
Put `SDL_Delay(10);` or `SDL_Delay(100);` between `SDL_RenderCopy` and `SDL_RenderPresent`. Just like that

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gTexture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_Delay(10);
SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);

SDL_Delay(1000);
```